# How to group the datatable vertically

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by

If I have datatable like this :

```
CompanyId   Year   Total1  Total2  Total3

 3022       2016   36.7     98.1   10.4
 3022       2015   77.3     55.3   98.4
 3011       2016   73.1     13.3   11.6
 3011       2015   33.6     10.9   8.1
```

How to get the following result: Grouping the data vertically like this:

```
          Total1        Total2        Total3
        2016  2015    2016  2015     2016  2015
 3022   36.7  77.3    98.1  55.3     10.4  98.4
 3011   73.1  33.6    13.3  10.9     11.6  8.1
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I try to do it through `SQl`  but it's so complicated because i have many tables and sub-queries , so i ask if it could be done by `LINQ` after i get the data through `SQL`

Comment: @TimSchmelter This Data table will be a datasource for my report so i want to bind the data like this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : It will be null or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a collection of anonymous types with the format you requested. Depending on what you intend to do, I suggest you create specific classes though

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        var result = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r["CompanyId"]).Select(c => new
            { Company = c.Key, Totals = c.Select(t => new
                {
                    Total1 = c.Select(t1 => new { Year = t1["Year"], Total1 = t1["Total1"] }).ToArray(),
                    Total2 = c.Select(t2 => new { Year = t2["Year"], Total2 = t2["Total2"] }).ToArray(),
                    Total3 = c.Select(t3 => new { Year = t3["Year"], Total3 = t3["Total3"] }).ToArray(),
                 }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();
            //ToArray() simply to make it visually cleaner in the object browser
    }
    static DataTable GetTable()  //Sample datatable I created
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("CompanyId", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Total1", typeof(decimal));
        table.Columns.Add("Total2", typeof(decimal));
        table.Columns.Add("Total3", typeof(decimal));

        table.Rows.Add(3022, 2016, 36.7, 98.1, 10.4);
        table.Rows.Add(3022, 2015, 77.3, 55.3, 98.4);
        table.Rows.Add(3011, 2016, 73.1, 13.3, 11.6);
        table.Rows.Add(3011, 2015, 33.6, 10.9, 8.1);
        return table;
    }
```

Explanation of the code:

First, I group the DataTable rows by CompanyId, which will result in 2 groups of 2 rows each.

For each group, I define an anonymous item (c) and give it two properties: **Company**, where I store the CompanyId and **Totals** which I will now dissect.

**Totals** is also defined as an anonymous class which consists of three properties **Total1**, **Total2** and **Total3**.

Each one of these is also implemented as an anonymous class, which contains the properties **Year**, and a 'Total' **decimal value**.

Since in this example each company posseses data of two different years, we will have 2 records of each 'Total'. Therefore:

```
Total1 = c.Select(t1 => new { Year = t1["Year"], Total1 = t1["Total1"]
```

will return two Total1 values, and in order to categorize and differentiate them, I stored them in an anonymous type together with the year attribute.

Comment: @Anyname Donotcare you deleted your comment? I hope I made myself clear this time

Comment: Thanks a lot , i just change your code a little bit, i use `First() instead of toArray() for one of them to avoid duplication of data